# Was BlobEncryptionPolicy removed for azure storage?

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to use client side encryption for azure to securely upload files to blob storage in .NET,

However it seems that BlobEncryptionPolicy is not available and I have not seen any documentation specifying alternative solutions from microsoft.

Even their documentation still uses BlobEncryptionPolicy:

[Client-Side Encryption and Azure Key Vault for Microsoft Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json)

Specifically i'm inside of a xamarin project using the latest .net version.

If i create a sample console app, I can reference BlobEncryptionPolicy without any issues. However the same nuget package inside a xamarin shared project can not resolve the reference to BlobEncryptionPolicy under the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob namespace.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: what happens when you try to specify BlobEncryptionPolicy? edit your question to specify that please

Comment: If my explanation does help, you could accept it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package depending on .net core and the one depending on .net framework.

You may have developed your Xamarin project based on .net core, where `BlobEncryptionPolicy` is not supported(this method doesn't exist in the dll).

As when you create a console app(.net framework), you can use the encryption. If you build a console app(.net core), you will find no such method as well.

[An open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/333) on github about this, saying the encryption for .net core is coming soon.

You can change your targetframework to use it if .net core is not necessary for your development.